# FlatBuffers C++ Minimum Version

Tags: flatbuffers

The FlatBuffers project requires a C++11 compiler to build. But what are the version requirements for the C++ header file *generated* by `flatc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are no different. The generated headers include `flatbuffers.h`, which depends on C++11.

That said, the it doesn't require the full C++11 feature set, it will build on compilers as old as Visual Studio 2010 and GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: g++ 4.4 & 4.5 seem to be supported as well, according to flatbuffers.h comments.

Comment: @AlexChe We have supported g++ 4.4 in the past, and we try to not break that compatibility, but we do not have CI set up with 4.4 so hard to say if it doesn't get broken on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I am using G++ 4.8.1. You just need to set -std=c++11 to get the features you need.